# EF Core one-to-zero relationship one way

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can a relationship one-to-one be created only one way?

```
public class Class1
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Class1Id { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Class2
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Class2Id { get; set; }

   public int? RelationshipId { get; set; }

   public virtual Class1 Relationship { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

And the configuration looks like this

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Class2> builder)
{
   builder.ToTable("...");

   builder.HasOne(m => m.Relationship)
     .WithOne()
     .HasForeignKey<Class1>(a => a.Class1Id);
}
```

But when I try to inspect the Relationship in an instance of Class2 I get something wrong. The RelationshipId has a value and the Relationship.Class1Id has a different value. The Relationship.Class1Id has the same value as Class2Id.

Does Class1 is required to have also a property of type Class2 in order for EF Core to work correctly?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Does Class1 is required to have also a property of type Class2 in order for EF Core to work correctly?

No. The mistake is in FK mapping:

```
.HasForeignKey<Class1>(a => a.Class1Id)
```

This way you are telling EF that it should use `Class1Id` property of the `Class1` as both PK and FK to `Class2`, in which case the `RelationshipId` property of `Class2` is not treated as a FK, but like any other simple property.

Instead, you should specify the FK property of the relationship (1) is on `Class2` and (2) is called `RelationshipId`:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Relationship)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Class2>(e => e.RelationshipId);
//                   ^                 ^
//                  (1)               (2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I got confused looking at the example with Author and AuthorBiography and mixed the classes