# EF Core 3.1 Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have two entities:

**The Audit class**:

```
public class Audit
{
  public string AuditId{get;set;}
  public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
  public virtual ModEmployee{get;set;}
}
```

**The Employee class**:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId{get;set}
}
```

While loading `Set<Audit>`, I want the Employee property of the Audit class to be populated.
This is clearly a case of One to Many relation, where one Audit will have one Employee but an Employee  can be in several Audits.

My Fluent API looks like below:

```
protected override OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Audit>()
 .HasOne(a=>a.ModEmployee)
 .WithMany()
 .HasForeignKey("EmployeeId");//a=>a.EmployeeId wont work.

}
```

I have been searching for a solution for sometime and took some inputs from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070328/ef-core-one-to-zero-relationship-one-way#) but its for One-To-One. Then [this resource](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) shows a way but that will require me to have a collection of Audits in the Employee class.

---

***I cant change the existing models or add annotations as they are already being used by some other entity framework version (not core).***

---

Presently I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
> relationship represented by navigation property 'Employee.ModEmployee' of
> type 'Employee'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore
> this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

If I add a ignore method on the builder of Audit the error goes away, like so: `.Ignore(a=>a.ModEmployee)` but I won't get the entity object inside Audit. Any help will be appreciated. I am on EFCore 3.1.10. Thanks for  reading.
Any help will be appreciated.

---

Comment: It's awkward that the error messages says  'Employee.ModEmployee'  instead of  'Audit.ModEmployee'. Did you try to remove the .HasForeignKey("EmployeeId")?

Comment: @heringer I haven’t, thinking that it will simply load the EmployeeId and won’t do anything about the ModEmplyee. But I see you have a point, will give it a try. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I tested your example and it worked as is in EF Core 3.1.10 and EF Core 5. It worked with and without your `OnModelCreating` configuration. The problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Just FYI the next setup `modelBuilder.Entity<Audit>().HasOne(a => a.ModEmployee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.EmployeeId);` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your type from `int` to `Employee` in the `Audit` class.
Should work fine because that's the correct way to relation a foreign key in the fluent API.

PS: the FK attribution string shall match the exact same inside the `Employee`, what's already happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. This worked for me:

Method 1:
Define your Employee class with the reference to the Audit collection:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set }
  public virtual ICollection<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your model builder define the relation this way:

```
builder.Entity<Audit>().HasOne(e => e.ModEmployee).WithMany(ae => ae.Audits).HasForeignKey(k => k.EmployeeId);
```

You always need to define the collection in every class.

EDIT!!

Method 2:

```
public class Audit
{
  public string AuditId{get;set;}
  public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I know this will need you to edit your class but trust me it will make the things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but like I said, I can’t change the models or add annotations as these classes are working just fine with EF6. I am writing a parallel flow for EFCore migration and hence have to use the same models.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do that then, the ICollection will not change anything in the database but EFCore wiil need to define where to "locally" store this retrived db rows. I used EF6 and EFCore in the same project and yet i didn't have any issues with this ICollection interface.

Comment: But then how is this existing set up working in EF6, with IsRequired(...).WithMany().HasForeignKey(...) methods!

Comment: You can just use the EFCore automatic binding. Define the audit class with a object reference to an Employee and this should automatically add a foreign key on your DB. I will edit my answer so you can wiew it correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify your model classes.

You can simply Add in your context a method to retrieve audits.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EFCoreFluentApi1.Context
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Employee>().HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
            builder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.EmployeeId);

            builder.Entity<Audit>().HasKey(e => e.AuditId);
            builder.Entity<Audit>().Property(e => e.AuditId);
            builder.Entity<Audit>().HasOne(e => e.ModEmployee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);

            builder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(new Employee[]
            {
                new Employee{ EmployeeId = 1 },
                new Employee{ EmployeeId = 2 },
                new Employee{ EmployeeId = 3 },
                new Employee{ EmployeeId = 4 }
            });

            builder.Entity<Audit>().HasData(
                new Audit[]
                {
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit1",
                        EmployeeId = 1
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit2",
                        EmployeeId = 1
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit3",
                        EmployeeId = 1
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit4",
                        EmployeeId = 2
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit5",
                        EmployeeId = 3
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit6",
                        EmployeeId = 3
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit7",
                        EmployeeId = 4
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit8",
                        EmployeeId = 4
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit9",
                        EmployeeId = 4
                    },
                    new Audit
                    {
                        AuditId = "Audit10",
                        EmployeeId = 4
                    }

                });
        }

        public ICollection<Audit> GetAudits(int employeeId)
        {
            return Audit.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

If you need populate ModEmployee, you can use the Include method.

```
using EFCoreFluentApi1.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace EFCoreFluentApi1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().
                    SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                    .Build();


            DbContextOptions options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true).Options;

            using (var context = new MyContext(options))
            {
                var result = context.Audit.Include(e => e.ModEmployee).ToList(); //ModEmployee is populated 
                //var result = context.Audit.ToList(); //ModEmployee = null
                foreach (var value in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"█ Audit: {value.AuditId}");
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check my example in https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/EFCoreFluentApi1
This project is `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`

Check IsRequired explicit
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#explicit-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is EFCore 3.1.10 and not EF. I ask because afaik,  ISRequired() is not something that would work on EFCore.

Comment: Check the URI to example. Updated Answer.

Comment: My bad, its HasRequired and not IsRequired. Will take a momnet to digest your answer.