# EF Core: how to specify foreign key in one-way relationships

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the `Entity Framework Core 6` fluent API to configure my database schema in a `.NET Core` project.

When declaring two-way relationships we can easily specify the foreign key like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Bars)
    .WithOne(x => x.Foo)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId);
```

However, if we have a one-way only relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Bar);
```

I don't understand how to specify the foreign key, since the `.HasOne` method does not return an object that has the `.HasForeignKey()` method.

How do you specify the foreign key in these cases?

Comment: `HasOne(...).WithOne().HasForeignKey(...)`.

Comment: From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.querytypebuilder-1.hasone) : After calling `HasOne`, you should chain a call to `WithMany` or `WithOne` to fully configure the relationship. Calling just this method without the chained call will not produce a valid relationship.

Comment: @vernou: thank you, I didn't realize that code wasn't actually creating a valid relationship

Comment: In other words, database tables must always have foreign keys. But navigation properties are optional. Foreign key properties may be shadow properties, and may be implicitly defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Bar)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Whatever);
```

Also this one maybe can help you too [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070328/ef-core-one-to-zero-relationship-one-way)

Comment: What is `e` in this context?

Comment: This didn't work for me and I ended up specifying the class type in HasForeignKey<Foo>

Answer (score 2):

Thinking by ER modeling, you will see that in a relationship one-one, the location of the Foreign key could be at the first table or second table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Bar)
        .WithOne(e => e.Foo)
        .HasForeignKey<Foo>(e => e.BarId);
```

Or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Bar)
        .WithOne(e => e.Foo)
        .HasForeignKey<Bar>(e => e.FooId);
```

It make sense when you see the code and got no suggestions, because you define where it will be (what table will got the FK).